# Incoming Connections with Two ISPs and Cisco 2911

Tags: cisco, isp, wide-area-network

I am a relatively beginner Networking Guy and I have managed to set up a Cisco 2911 router with two ISPs (no BGP), NAT and route-maps (although I don't really understand them) to the two up links with one default route and another floating static route.

My question is this: Since only one uplink is active at a time, I am not able to receive incoming connections from the redundant link as on the way back they are router through the default route (not the floating one which they came in from).

Is there any way I can have data incoming from the redundant link, go back through the redundant link? I would appreciate if you can also supply some example commands with your response.

For reference, here are some excerpts of my configuration:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description LAN
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip flow ingress
 ip flow egress
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!

interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description GO Primary Connection
 no ip address
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 pppoe enable group global
 pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
!

interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 description Melita Redundant Connection
 ip address 213.165.160.28 255.255.255.240
 ip nat outside
 no ip virtual-reassembly in
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1452
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!

interface Dialer1
 description GO Primary Connection Dialer
 ip address negotiated
 ip mtu 1492
 ip nat outside
 no ip virtual-reassembly in
 encapsulation ppp
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1452
 dialer pool 1
 dialer idle-timeout 0
 dialer persistent
 dialer-group 1
 ppp authentication pap callin
 ppp chap hostname ****
 ppp chap password 0 ****
 ppp pap sent-username **** password 0 ****
!

ip nat inside source route-map GO interface Dialer1 overload
ip nat inside source route-map Melita interface GigabitEthernet0/2 overload

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer1
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 213.165.160.17 20

route-map GO permit 10
   match ip address 1
   match interface Dialer1
!

route-map Melita permit 10
   match ip address 1
   match interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!

access-list 1 permit 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
```

Comment: Need to see the interface configurations and nat configurations

Comment: @JasonSeemann I updated the question with the interface and NAT configurations